# How to convert string array to numpy array and pass it to UDF in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've stored a Numpy array as a string array in CSV file (didn't know any other way). Now there are two problems I am facing

1) I need to read the CSV file and convert the string array to numpy array and pass it to the UDF.

2) Why I'm not able to use the DF.withcolumn method? It throws below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
>   1989, in withColumn
>       assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column" AssertionError: col should be Column

My code snippet -

```
def wantNumpyArr(array):
    try:
      //some code//
    except Exception:
       pass
    else:
      return float_var

spark.udf.register("wantNumpyArr", wantNumpyArr, FloatType())

#Read from csv file
read_data=spark.read.format("csv").load("/path/to/file/part-*.csv", header="true")
rdd = read_data.rdd

convert_data = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], wantNumpyArr(x[2])))
```

When I print the convert_data RDD it always have the 3rd column value as "None" which means the flow in the UDF always goes in Except block.
Sample data -

```
[Row(Id='ABCD505936', some_string='XCOYNZGAE', array='[0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]')]
```

The schema of the DF is -

```
print (read_data.schema)
StructType(List(StructField(col1,StringType,true),StructField(col2,StringType,true),StructField(col3,StringType,true)))
```

Comment: try to understand what happens inside the UDF. You suspect that an exception is thrown - find that out for sure. Remove the except clause and see what happens.

Comment: You will be wasting a lot of time/resources by doing the conversion. Use a pandas_udf https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html the data will be converted automatically to pandas dataframe which is a wrapper on top of numpy